# Vertical and Horizontal Center Align with Flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Centered Align content in Box using CSS Flex box.
For both side vertical and Horizontal Middle align of Content in Specific sized Box.

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And the above apply on a [self-answered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235177/what-are-limitations-on-self-answered-questions) as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
.container{width:500px;height:200px;background-color:#333;display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;}
  
 h1{color:#fff;}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <h1>
  Hello Wolrd
  </h1>
</div>
```